# About Codeigniter Members Count?

Tags: codeigniter

How can I make show the total number of members registered in Codeigniter?

I need model, controller, view codes.

I would appreciate if you help.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. What you are asking to do can be accomplished in a number of ways. Do some research, make and effort, and come back when/if you have any problems along the way.

Comment: How do you think I didn't do research? I just started and I couldn't. I wanted help, that's all.

Comment: Then post what you have thus far, we aren't mind readers and can't guess your db schema, current code .etc. as it stands your question is "give me the codes" which doesn't work here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Plus if you did research you would have found this:  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results or even `num_rows()`

Answer (score 1):

**As you didn't give us more code and information though.** I think you want to display the total number of users registered in your view, write this part of the code where you want to count the number.

```
  <?php 
      $this->load->model('admindash_model');
      $count_users = count($this->admindash_model->get());
      print $count_users;
   ?>
```

> I think this will going to help you. If you could understand and place
>   it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
public function get(){
       $this->db->select('gorun');
       $this->db->from('users');
       $this->db->where('gorun', '0' );
       return $this->db->count_all_results(); 
 }
```

Controller:

```
public function admindash(){
       $this->load->model("admindash_model");    
       $results = $this->admindash_model->get();
}
```

Comment: Code works but can't show in view. How can I do it?